# How to control color for an Ansible message (foreground and background)?

Tags: colors, ansible

Looking at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html there is no mention of how to control the foreground and background colors for text. Is it possible to control that?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to [configure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) colors in the configuration file and/or in the environment variable.

For example for [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#color-debug)

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory = $PWD/hosts
...
[colors]
debug = red
deprecate = bright purple
changed = purple
```

or

```ini
shell> set | grep ANSIBLE_COLOR_DEBUG
ANSIBLE_COLOR_DEBUG=red
```

---

Q: ***"Is it possible to show the output of tasks in different colors?"***

A: Yes. The colors depend on your setting. See for example [Solarized](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/)

```ini
[colors]
changed = purple
debug = bright yellow
deprecate = blue
diff_add = green
diff_lines = cyan
diff_remove = red
error = red
highlight = white
ok = green
skip = yellow
unreachable = bright red
verbose = blue
warn = bright purple
```

---

Q: ***"Is it possible to control task-wise?"***

A: No. It's not possible to set the colors in a play, role, block, or task. See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). You can set colors either in the configuration or in the environment. See [Common Options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#common-options).

Comment: Is it possible to show the output of tasks in different colours ? Is it possible to control task-wise ?

Comment: [example](https://photos.app.goo.gl/3W61ZSBuAwx1PSVq6)